# rails search multiple attributes of multiple modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, nested-attributes

I'm trying to search all columns in my `Ticket` model. Most columns are assocaited with a `belongs_to` association so I have to search the attributes of the info in my columns because people won't know the IDs.

These articles helped:
[Search multiple db columns in Rails 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422489/search-multiple-db-columns-in-rails-3-0)

[Rails: Search in has_one association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337543/rails-search-in-has-one-association)

So far I have the below code, but it only searches the top param. How can I get it so that if it doesn't find anything in the top search, it tries the next. I'll be adding more to this.

Thanks

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    Ticket.joins(:submitter).where('first_name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  elsif  
    Ticket.joins(:issue).where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    all
  end
end
```

I figured it out, updated correct code here:

```
def self.search(search)
case search 
when /^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/
  Ticket.find(:all, :conditions => ['id LIKE :search', {:search => "%#{search}%"}])
else
  Ticket.joins(:submitter,:issue).find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE :search OR first_name LIKE :search', {:search => "%#{search}%"}])
end
end
```

Comment: what's being passed in as the argument to the function?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder => "Search tickets", :type => "search" %>`

Comment: This is in my Ticket controller `@tickets = Ticket.where(:school_id => @current_user.school_id).order('id DESC').search(params[:search])`

Answer (score 1):

Updated code above - answer found